# Condition for roots of $x^2+xy+y^2\in\mathbb{F}_{q^n}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $q$ be a prime number and $n$ an integer.

Is there some number theoretic condition involving the numbers $q,n$ that can tell me when is the polynomial 
$$x^2+xy+y^2\in\mathbb{F}_{q^n}[x,y]$$

doesn't have roots other than ones with $x=y$.

Comment: Unless $q = 3$, I can't see how $x=y$ would produce roots, other than $x=y=0$...

Comment: Ignoring the solution $x=y=0$. By the quadratic formula $x^{2} + xy + y^{2} = 0$ only when $x = \left( \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2} \right)y$. Thus $x^{2} + xy + y^{2} = 0$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}\left[x,y\right]$ has no roots if and only if $q \neq 2$ and $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ has no square roots of $-3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ As  @JyrkiLahtonen pointed out in the comments, there is a much simpler argument here. $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ contains a primitive third root of unity if and only if $3$ divides $q^{n} - 1$. This is because the multiplicative group of a field of size $q^{n}$ is always cyclic of order $q^{n} - 1$, and a cyclic group contains an element of prime order $p$ for every prime dividing its size. Thus $x^{2} + xy + y^{2}$ has non-zero solutions in $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ whenever $q^{n} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 3)$. Thus if $q \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 3)$ then our equation has non-zero solutions, else $q \equiv 2 \ (\text{mod} \ 3)$ and then $q^{n} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 3)$ if and only if $n$ is even. Giving the complete solution that this equation has no non-zero solutions only when $q \equiv 2 \ (\text{mod} \ 3)$ and $n$ is odd.

I'm gonna leave my original attempt up in case it is at all enlightening for anyone.

---

Following on from my answer in the comments. Ignoring the solution $x=y=0$ which you have for every $q$, and suppose also for now that $q \neq 2$. Then by the quadratic formula $x^{2} + xy + y^{2} = 0$ only  when

$$
x = \left( \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-3}}{2} \right) y,
$$

and so are interested when the field $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ contains square roots of $-3$. Let us first consider the case $n=1$. I'm not sure how much elementary number theory you know, but the problem of whether or not the finite field of a prime number of elements contains the square root of a number is given the Legendre symbol. That is for $q$ a prime number, and $a$ an integer, then

$$
\left( \frac{a}{q} \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l} 
1, & \text{if} \ a \not\equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ q) \ \text{is a quadratic residue in} \ \mathbb{F}_{q} \\
-1, & \text{if} \ a \not\equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ q) \ \text{is not a quadratic residue in} \ \mathbb{F}_{q} \\ 
0, & \text{if} \ a \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ q)
   \end{array}\right.
$$

where the phrase "quadratic residue" exactly means that it is the square of something in that field. Thus this problem is reduced this figuring out the value of $\left( \frac{-3}{q} \right)$. This symbol has the following properties.

$$
\left( \frac{1}{q} \right) = 1 \ \text{for all primes} \ q,
$$
$$
\left( \frac{ab}{q} \right) = \left( \frac{a}{q} \right) \left( \frac{b}{q} \right) \ \text{for all integers} \ a,b \ \text{and primes} \ q,
$$
$$
\left( \frac{a + kq}{q} \right) = \left(\frac{a}{q}\right) \ \text{for all integers} \ a,k \ \text{and primes} \ q.
$$

We also have quadratic reciprocity. That is, if $p,q$ are two distinct odd primes then

$$
\left( \frac{p}{q} \right)\left( \frac{q}{p} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}}
$$

Using these properties we can see that (so long as $q \neq 3$)

$$
\left( \frac{-3}{q} \right) = \left( \frac{-1}{q} \right)\left( \frac{3}{q} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\left( \frac{-1}{q} \right)\left( \frac{q}{3} \right) 
$$

Now using these (and maybe [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) , one works out that

$$
\left( \frac{-1}{q} \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l}
1, & \text{if}  \ q \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 4) \\
-1,& \text{if}  \ q \equiv 3 \ (\text{mod} \ 4) 
 \end{array}\right.
$$

and

$$
\left( \frac{3}{q} \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l}
1, & \text{if}  \ q \equiv 1,11 \ (\text{mod} \ 12) \\
-1,& \text{if}  \ q \equiv 5,7 \ (\text{mod} \ 12) 
 \end{array}\right.
$$

This allows us to calculate that

$$
\left( \frac{-3}{q} \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l}
1, & \text{if}  \ q \equiv 1,7 \ (\text{mod} \ 12) \\
-1,& \text{if}  \ q \equiv 5,11 \ (\text{mod} \ 12) 
 \end{array}\right.
$$

This answers your question when $n=1$. When $n = 2$ we need to use a little bit of algebra. Again suppose that $q \neq 2$, and suppose we have a case where $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ does not have a square root of $-3$, then $x^{2} + 3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$, and so can be used to generated the field extension $\mathbb{F}_{q^{2}}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, thus since all finite fields of the same order are isomorphic $\mathbb{F}_{q^{2}}$ must always contain a square root of $-3$. Thus any field extension of $\mathbb{F}_{q^{2}}$ contains a square root of $-3$ and thus $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ contains a square root of $-3$ whenever $n$ is even.

I know this isn't a complete answer, but I hope it goes some way to showing the sorts of things you need to think about when tackling this question. See if you can use these ideas to tackle the case when $n$ is not even, or when $q = 2, 3$.

Comment: This is the right idea. It might be simpler to explain that $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ contains $\sqrt{-3}$ if and only if it contains a third primitive root of unity $\omega=(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ if and only if $3\mid q^n-1$ (by cyclicity of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}^*$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is much simpler! Does your argument work when $q=2$?

Comment: Yes. The group $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}^*$ is cyclic of order $q^n-1$ even when $q=2$. And a cyclic group has elements of order three iff the order is a multiple of three.

Comment: Of course, $\Bbb{F}_q[\sqrt{-3}]$ is always a quadratic extension at worst, so we can also say that $\omega$ is in there whenever either $q\equiv1\pmod3$ or $n$ is even.

Comment: Yeah I caught the case that $n$ is even. Just missed the much simpler argument about $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}^{\times}$ being cyclic, and a cyclic groups contains an element of prime order for every prime dividing the size of the group.

Comment: Thanks, but what if $q=2$?

Comment: @user621824 if $q=2$ then this equation has no non-zero solutions whenever $n$ is odd.

Comment: @AdamHiggins But when $q=2$ we cannot use the quadratic formula ?

Comment: True, but in the extra comment I added, we were not using the quadratic formula. Note that $x^{2} + xy + y^{2} = \frac{x^{3} - y^{3}}{x-y}$, and so our equation has no solutions $x \neq y$ if and only if we have no pairs $x \neq y$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ such that $x^{3} = y^{3}$. But this is equivalent to whether or not  $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ has an element $\xi \neq 1$ such that $\xi^{3} = 1$, that is whether or not $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ has a primitive third root of unity. So we're essentially solving whether or not the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ has an element of order $3$

Comment: The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ is the cyclic group of order $q^{n} - 1$, and this has an element of order $3$ if and only if $3 \vert q^{n} - 1$ (This is a direct consequence of Cauchy's theorem). Thus this equation has no solutions $x \neq y$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ if and only if $3$ does not divide $q^{n} - 1$, which is if and only if $q \equiv 2 \ ( \text{mod} \ 3)$, and $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thus, we have solved this equation without using the quadratic formula, and we have made no exceptions for when $q=2$, and so we conclude that since $2 \equiv 2 \ (\text{mod} \ 3)$ this equation has no solutions $x \neq y$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{n}}$ if and only if $n$ is odd.

Comment: @user621824 Upvoting your question simply for the observation that  the quadratic formula cannot be used when $q=2$! Well done! Adam did cover that case as well, but, yeah, I neglected to explain that.